# PowerShellAccessControl Module 3.0 output

Tags: powershell

Does anyone knows what `O CC CO` under the "Applied To" in the output of the following `Get-AccessControlEntry` command means?

```
PS> Get-ADUser tuser | Get-AccessControlEntry -ObjectAceType memberof -ActiveDirectoryRights ReadProperty

AceType        Principal                 AccessMask              InheritedFrom    AppliesTo  OnlyAppliesHere
-------        ---------                 ----------              -------------    ---------  ---------------
AccessAllowed  Prod\ADR-CanGet_memberOf  Read memberOf Property  <not inherited>  O CC CO    False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going out on a limb I'd say it stands for **O**bject, **C**hild**C**ontainers and **C**hild**O**bjects.